# Renew apple developer membership after it expires

Tags: icloud, developer-program

I had an app on the appstore and a few days ago my membership expired. I want to renew it now, but when I click on the renew membership button, it takes me to the apple website with some sort of referral code on top.

How can I proceed to renew my membership?

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Try using Safari?

Answer (score 1):

You need to just wait and try again in an hour or two. The Apple Store is down right now  pending the new products that can be pre-ordered later today (in about an hour).

Comment: i wasn't aware of that, thank you!